# How can I add an Array of [SCNNode?] to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am currently working on my very first App and I don't find a solution for this. 
I have an Array of SCNNodes which I want to add to the UserDefaults.
However, with my current solution, the game always crashes:

var ship = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!

var ship2 = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship2.scn")?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship2", recursively: true)!

```
func setupArray() {
    let ships = [ship,ship2]
    UserDefaults.standard.set(ships, forKey: "ShipsToPlace")
    let savedShips = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "ShipsToPlace") as? [SCNNode] ?? [SCNNode]()
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to add `SCNNode`s to user defaults, you're probably doing something wrong. What is it that you actually want to store? Surely not the whole node, right? Yes, I know it'd be convenient to be able to just save and retrieve a whole node, but you _should_ only store the data you need. And when you retrieve the data, _recreate_ the nodes from the data.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering that quick. You are right, I've been on a totally wrong way. But you have brought me to an Idea. Thanks a Lot